# How to change the size of the label automatically in table cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

How to change the size of the label automatically in table cells?

I've already written

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 240
```

in `viewDidLoad()`,

and

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

and already set "Lines" 0 to show text in multiple lines.

so, if I set the text previously, it shows text in a few lines and change the size of the label automatically, but if I make a display to input text and the label shows what I input, it becomes in a line and doesn't change the size of the label.

What else do I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to reload that Cell !! , After each change happen you need to reload that cell to reflect  on UI , also don't forgot to write layoutIfNeeded

Comment: Thanks for a comment. How can I reload that cell?

Comment: You have indexpath for current editing cell then just reload that indexPath then             `t.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.init(0))`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's been just solved by reloading!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to update a particular UITableView Cell :

```
func updateCell(path:Int){
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: path, inSection: 1)

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) //try other animations
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To realod, I added

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Hope it helps you write these two lines in view did load

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Sorry my code part is hard to read, but I've already done it. What else idea do you have?